# Indexes slowing Insertions(Can't use Explain Insert to Analyse)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a `MySQL` database,  I am parsing files from a log and inputting it inside.

So far including a simple 4MB file in the database could take me about 4 minutes to insert ! and i have about 10,000 of such files to process.

At first i thought it's my script but after further digging i learned that this could be related to indexes.

I have a table with `4 columns, 1 primary key and 2 foreign keys which are by default indexes`.

From this is it possible to know if the indexes affect insertion performances ? I can't seem to use Explain Insert with `MySQL` so i don't know of any more information to provide.

```
CREATE TABLE `as_path` (
  `AS_Path_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Path_Index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AS_No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Update_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AS_Path_ID`,`Update_ID`,`AS_No`),
  KEY `AS_No_fk_idx` (`AS_No`),
  KEY `Update_ID_fk_as_path_idx` (`Update_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `AS_No_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`AS_No`) REFERENCES `as_detail` (`AS_No`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Update_ID_fk_as_path` FOREIGN KEY (`Update_ID`) REFERENCES `update_detail` (`Update_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1074256 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

A file of 4 MB should not take 4 minutes to insert.I see your table have InnoDB engine.

I hope you first need to optimize basic InnoDB settings for that please have a look at [Innodb Performance Optimization Basics](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/)

**Now How to speed up InnoDB Inserts**

There's an entire [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)  dedicated to bulk loading data into InnoDB. The main points:

1. disable autocommit to avoid an extra log flush for each insert statement: SET autocommit=0;...sql import;COMMIT;
2. disable foreign and unique checks (you can't disable all indexes completely):
   SET unique_checks=0;
   SET foreign_key_checks=0;

Setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 (or 2)` may also speedup inserts. Please note, ACID rules would love that value to be at 1.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to indexes. Think about how a constraint could affect inserts. PK is unique by design and you have three columns and with your 3 col PK MySQL needs to check each time a new row is inserted whether that PK is unique. Why can you not simply use the 1st column as your PK? Secondary keys need to be updated when you add new data, ensure that you have expand_fast_index_creation turned on. FK relationships need to be maintained based on their inclusion in the table. What rippling effect does your INSERT have on related tables?

On the other hand it might be due to your settings. Check and tune the following:
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_log_file_size
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Some tweaks to these could spin you up a few notches.

Comment: sorry i created this account whereby i can't comment without having 50 points. Since i created the tables using workbench and linked the foreign keys, those indexes where automatically created as well. Please what may i do exactly ? is there an option on workbench such as to turn on expand_fast_index ? I will check the tunes. I have a table called updates that a date is inserted in with some few data and the rest is carried to that table which slows everything down.